# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'description' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `projects` (...)

Tags: php, laravel

I got an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'description' doesn't have
>   a default value (SQL: insert into `projects` (`title`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (projet 5, 2019-03-01 22:13:19, 2019-03-01
>   22:13:19))

class **ProjectController.php**

```
public function create()
{
   return view('projects.create');
}
public function store()
{
   //dd(request()->all());
   Project::create(request(['title','description']));
   return redirect('/projects');
}
```

class **Project.php**

```
class Project extends Model
{
  protected $fillable=[
     'title','description'
   ];
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('projects','ProjectsController');
```

I can't insert a project and I check my fields in phpMyadmin and everything is ok.

Comment: I don't see the description in your insert and the DB is telling you that this field needs a value. You can update your http request passing the value from the client or alter your table adding a default to this field.

Comment: please try `Project::create(request()->only(['title','description']));`

Comment: @dparoli the same problem

Comment: @abn i have passed the field description in the DB Project::create(request(['title','description']));

Comment: Review your form, you probably mispelled the input for description. I can only think that the description is not present in your request.

Comment: Another thing. I don't see the request object being passed to the function store.                `function store ( Request $request)`

Comment: @dparoli I filled out the form and i check the input for description :'(

Comment: @abn why i need to use $request ? iI'm following a tutorial and he code it like that and it works for him

Comment: try to `dd(request()->only(['title','description']))` in the controller and see what you get. I guess description is not present.

Comment: @dparoli yes you are right it returns : array:1 [ "title" => "projcet 1"] where shall i add the des description please ?

Comment: Please review the form you use to enter the data, the input for the title is present but the input for description is or not present or incorrect.

Comment: @dparoli okey thank you very much